# Prices not changing as per country because of varnish , Any idea?

Tags: price, varnish, magento2.4.5p1

I have varnish configured and its works fine but its not allowing to change the price block as per countries.

Varnish is storing prices in caching so how can i make prices works dynamically ?

*Without cacheable="false".*

Comment: Can you please share your VCL configuration and a screenshot of the Varnish configuration inside the Magento admin panel. I'm trying to figure out if your setup is properly configured to deal with caching purging calls.

Answer (score 2):

Can use http context or private content for bypass cache

1. Http context: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/cache/page/public-content/#configure-page-variations
2. Private content: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/cache/page/private-content/